# How to access hpsockd access log?

Tags: debian, debian-jessie

Since in Debian the only available SOCKS5 server through the standard repos is `hpsockd` I gave the server a try.

Now I'm having problems with some connections and need to debug the connections running through this daemon. The log variables are configured, but I cannot figure out how to read the usage log - the content of the file is binary goo and I could not find any documentation on how to read it.

So, how do you read the usage log of sockd? Do I need an additional tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortly:

```
/usr/lib/hpsockd/log2ascii /var/cache/hpsockd/usage.log
```

Debian package hpsockd has not detailed documentation ..
The syntax of the configuration file can be found in */usr/share/doc/hpsockd/html/*

An example configuration file */etc/hpsockd.conf* is here: */usr/share/doc/hpsockd/examples/hpsockd.conf*

There you can also find instructions for **Socks Daemon Control**:
 ***/usr/sbin/sdc**
 [-c config] status [interval]|reload|newlog|dumpconfig|dumpclient|unlisten|stop|start|restart*

Logging configuration settings (hpsockd.conf):

```
logging {
       facility        "daemon";
       level           2;
        dump-prefix     "sockd.dump";           # if not specified, you get no dumps
        usage-log       "usage.log";            # if not specified, you get no logging
};
```

The file *usage.log* is in the directory */var/cache/hpsockd*. This is a *Directory* option from the *daemon* configuration section.

Reading the binary log is possible by using the utility **/usr/lib/hpsockd/log2ascii**, which is part of the installation package..

Comment: This needs more details / explanations to be a useful answer.

Comment: I don't get it ...

Comment: So it is important that answer helps others who will solve the same problem as the original query...
@Pierre.Vriens Sorry, but what is incomprehensible?:
Question: "How do you read the usage log of sockd?"
Answer: "/usr/lib/hpsockd/log2ascii  usage.log"

Comment: @jaha2x : **NOW** the quality of your answer is way better! ... At least to me ... so +1!